# How to split playframwork 2 log file into days?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

How to split playframwork 2 **log file** into days?
For example i wanna get files like this:
logs/application20130601.log
logs/application20130602.log
logs/application20130603.log
logs/application20130604.log

Answer (score 2):

Logback rocks.  You need to use a RollingFileAppender and set up the rollingPolicy.  My logging is such that the application's log is always named app.log and it rolls on the day change into app.yyyyMMdd.log on the day change.  Here is the logger.xml to achieve this.

```
<appender name="DAILY_ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>logs/app.log</File>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <FileNamePattern>logs/app.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log</FileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'} [%p] %c{2} - %m%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

This gets the current day as logs/app.log and yesterday as, for example, logs/app.20130612.log.

Answer (score 1):

The play Logger is built on Log4j. They does have a way to split logging date-wise. The method name is DailyRollingFileAppender. Check this [link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/Logger.html)

Your problem was already inquired upon and answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091592/datewise-log-files-using-log4j)

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

play framework 2 using 'logback'
refer to : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/SettingsLogger

you will define a  'conf/application-logger.xml' and you see next link

http://blog.mograbi.info/2013/03/setting-logback-with-playframework-20.html